# Referencing pair of subequations as (1a,b) using cleveref

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

If I have subequations (1a) and (1b), then when I reference them using `\cref` I would like them to be typeset as (1a,b), but by default they appear as (1a) and (1b). How do I change this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[compress]{cleveref}
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}#2#6)}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    a&=b    \label{eqn:1a}\\
    c&=d    \label{eqn:1b}\\
    e&=f    \label{eqn:1c}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
    x=y     \label{eqn:2}
\end{equation}

Reference to the trio of equations works correctly as a range: `\cref{eqn:1a,eqn:1b,eqn:1c}', 
but reference to a pair yields `\cref{eqn:1a,eqn:1b}' when I want `eqs. (1a,b)'. In addition, 
I would like `\cref{eqn:1a,eqn:1b,eqn:2}' to appear as 'eqs. (1a,b) and (2)'.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That gets a hyphen, not a comma.

Comment: It should be (1a,b) and (1a-c)

Answer (score 1):

The `cleveref` package offers a low-level macro called `\crefrangelabelformat`, but it doesn't offer a macro called `\crefpairlabelformat`. Hence, as you've discovered, `\cref{eqn:1a,eqn:1b}` uses the simple conjunction "and".

Short of contacting the author and maintainer of the `cleveref` package and asking him to create a macro called `\crefpairlabelformat` for you, you could (almost -- with an en-dash in place of a comma) obtain the desired output format when cross-referencing a pair of (sub)equations by typing

```
\crefrange{eqn:1a}{eqn:1b}
```

Similarly, you could input `\crefrange{eqn:1a}{eqn:1b} and \labelcref{eqn:2}` to obtain `eqs. (1a--b) and (2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have sent an email, I'll see what Toby says!

Comment: @Eddy - Did you contact Toby Cubitt with your feature request for a macro that might be called `\crefpairlabelformat`? If so, what was his response?

Comment: There was no response, I think the email address may not be active any more.

Comment: @Eddy - Many thanks for your quick reply. It's rather unfortunate that Toby hasn't replied to your inquiry. I've just sent him an email message as well. I'll let you know if I get a response from him.